Old comic in which a guy is captured/enslaved by (aliens?) and turned into a cyborg hunter killer or something
I am trying to find an old comic about a killer cyborg. I think the comic is either from 1970s-1980s (could be VERY early 90s). I got the comic in a "mystery" bag with a bunch of DC/Marvel/Eclipse comics. This is NOT for Deathlok (marvel) or Cyborg (DC).
I remember that this guy is captured/enslaved by (aliens?) and the first page in the comic is him telling them "Go to Hell" and then the panels show them stripping away his face off, then he is left with muscle, then the top of his head is open showing his brain, then they finally put him in the cybernetic (armor?) to be a hunter killer or something.
I remember the cover has him on it and it appears to be a dystopian future. The cover had an art style similar to Transformers #5 with Shockwave on it, but the art inside felt more like 70s-80s DC/Marvel.
I'm guessing this is quite an obscure comic, as I've spent many hours online pouring over issues trying to find it with no luck.

It is a DC comic called Electric Warrior!
  

The series in set in a future where the rich (Elites) live in luxury, their lifestyles supported by an array of cybernetic devices and robots, while the poor (Zigs) are forced to struggle for their existence in the lower levels of the city. When one of the robot policemen, known as the Electric Warriors, or Leks, develops self-awareness, it begins to question the correctness of the social order and decides to help the Zigs. This robot is called 9-03, and it falls in love with a Zig crone called Kinsolving, whom he protects from any and all harm. He then helps the Zigs by giving them food and supplies taken from the Elites up above.
At the same time, a man named Derek Two-Shadow is living in the forest with a tribe of natural born natives called Primmies. They have rejected all forms of modern technology. A female scholar, Quintana, is sent into the forest to live with the Primmies and study them. She gets to know Derek Two-Shadow, and learns of his history and life. He was born as a Zig, but escaped to the wilderness when he was still a child. One night, a group of genetic mutants (Genidiots) sneaks into the Primmie camp to steal food. Quintana is startled to see one, and she shoots and kills three of them with her laser pistol. She did not know that the Genidiots were allowed to steal food in exchange for peace between the two factions. With the killing of the three intruders, the peace is broken and the Genidiots will attack. She offers her weapons to defend the village, but since this goes against the Primmie principle of rejecting technology, she is told to leave and never come back.
When the Leks sent to capture 9-03 learn of Kinsolving's close relationship with 9-03, they decide to kidnap her and take her to headquarters for further questioning. 9-03 storms into the Elite leader's office and demands he release Kinsolving. The leader's name is Magistrate Marder. He agrees to free Kinsolving in exchange for letting his techs examine 9-03 and figure out how he became sentient. 9-03 manages to free Kinsolving, but when a group of gunships sent to pursue them fires a warning shot, 9-03 sees that the shot is going to kill a Zig family. He throws himself in front of the shot and saves the Zigs, but he is blown to pieces.
Magistrate Marder has learned about a fleet of what appear to be alien vessels and wishes to fuse man and machine to create a new breed of Electric Warrior, the Synthoids. He had hoped to duplicate 9-03's autonomy and intelligence, but since that failed, he has the Primmies rounded up, captured, then taken to the city where they are converted into cyborgs and most of them die from the shock. Two-Shadow, however, is one of the lucky ones: the components of 9-03 are fused to his body after most of it has been amputated. Upon awakening after his surgery, Derek feels the essence of 9-03 within his altered body, escapes, and finds a component of the robot at Kinsolving's home that he uses to flood his body with nanites and merge 9-03's mind with his own; although they retain their independent brain patterns, they can never again be separated.
The Electric Warrior forces an alliance between the Primmies, Zigs, Genidiots, and Elites to fight the invasion, but when the "aliens" come, they are revealed to be very human – the Electric Warrior's planet had been an experiment set up to determine how civilizations develop. Derek Two-Shadow was actually a resident of Earth who had signed up for the experiment after discovering that his wife had had herself rendered cybernetically immortal. This disgusted him into leaving her forever due to the fact that the surgery required had left horrible scars on her back and her body had been changed so that they could no longer enjoy a normal physical relationship. The Electric Warrior agrees to go back to Earth with the "aliens" to give them their experimental data, while the rest of the people remain behind but in a more mutually beneficial and cooperative peace.

https://www.etsy.com/listing/1032873710/vintage-dc-comics-the-electric-warrior

Hi, it's great you found it.  Etsy listings in particular tend to disappear after a while, so it would be great if you copied over the relevant information to your answer here.

We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

You may be thinking of Armor (1985–1993) by Continuity Comics.

The basic story as I remember is is that a young athlete is captured by invading aliens (the area is gassed to do so). He's tortured and put through a deadly training regime to hone him into the ultimate assassin. He ends up rebelling against the alien warlord who created him.
It's been a long time since I've read this and I don't think I have it anymore, but I do recall he tells the warlord to "go to hell" (or similar) when first captured. I don't recall his face being removed but he is tortured with a bladed machine during his breaking and "transformation" into Armor.
I got my copy in a bargain bin, packaged with another comic (Chromium Man by Triumphant Comics). I'm not sure if this was CC's regular distribution strategy or if they were packaged this way by the store to get rid of them.

Nah, wasn't Armor, but letting me know about Triumphant Comics be me helpful. He was definitely a Cyborg though in the comic book. I'll look into Continuity Comics too, thank you though!

@ntemplar Ah, too bad. Sorry. I will say that Continuity had a lot of really weird/offbeat comics like this. I had thought Chromium Man was by CC as well but when I looked it up for this answer I realized it wasn't. But CC did Bucky O'Hare, Magnus: Robot Hunter, and a bunch of other weird titles. I hope that'll at least point you in the right direction. good luck!

Maybe Deathlok the Demolisher?
Deathlok is a rather obscure Marvel character, who first appeared in Astonishing Tales #25, 1974 (cover below is from a reprint collection). In a dystopian future, Luther Manning is turned (by humans, not aliens) into a deadly cyborg.
Several later characters have shared the name and general looks, but with differing origins.


Not Deathlok either, I mentioned that in the original post but he gives off those vibes. This comic had more gore in it than Marvel would have put in at the time. It wasn't Captain Power, but the cyborg looked like a more borged-out version of Lord Dredd from Captain Power, he was part of a hunter killer unit I think. Thanks for the thought though!
